# psql table description

Tags: postgresql

in psql if i do `\d+`, I get something like

```
 Schema |          Name           |   Type   | Owner  |    Size    |     Description 
--------+-------------------------+----------+--------+------------+-------------
 norsar | Routing Result          | table    | morten | 16 kB      | 
 norsar | Routing Result_id_seq   | sequence | morten | 8192 bytes |
```

and so on. The last field, "Description" is always blank. Where does that field read its content? - and thereby, how can I set a description on a table? In some cases that could be quite useful - the same thing for description on columns that are shown if i do `\d+ <tablename>`.

I have tried `\set ECHO_HIDDEN ON`, but that didn't make it much clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That shows comments that you define using the command [`comment on`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-comment.html):

The following table definition:

```
create table foo
(
  id integer primary key, 
  name text not null
);

comment on table foo is 'This is the famous foo table';
comment on column foo.id is 'This is the primary key';
comment on column foo.name is 'This is the name of the thing';
```

Will then show up like this:

```
postgres> \d+
                                List of relations
 Schema |   Name    | Type  | Owner  |    Size    |         Description
--------+-----------+-------+--------+------------+------------------------------
 public | foo       | table | thomas | 8192 bytes | This is the famous foo table
(1 row)

postgres> \d+ foo
                                             Table "public.foo"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Stats target |          Description
--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------+-------------------------------
 id     | integer |           | not null |         | plain    |              | This is the primary key
 name   | text    |           | not null |         | extended |              | This is the name of the thing
Indexes:
    "foo_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)


postgres>
```